# PYTHON/PYQT5 - window not opening when button clicked from main file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a movie theatre booking system and ive been facing an issue when trying to open a window.

After the user selects a movie and clicks 'Book' its supposed to open the window which shows all of the movies showtimings.
When I run the code from the main file `main.py`, the book button does not have any response, but when I run the individual file for that window, and click the book button it works perfectly fine.

This is the code for the window that displays the information of the movie. (`ui_movieinfo.py`)

```
class Ui_MovieInfoWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.booking = Ui_MovieBookingWindow()

    def openmoviebookingscreen(self):
        self.booking.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, MovieInfoWindow):
        if not MovieInfoWindow.objectName():
            MovieInfoWindow.setObjectName(u"MovieInfoWindow")
        MovieInfoWindow.resize(1920, 1080)

        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily(u"Yu Gothic UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(9)

        with open(r'CineDeck\window_code\mov.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.x = f.readline()

        q = "SELECT movie_name, movie_poster, movie_desc, movie_price, movie_rating, cast, runtime, director, languages, genre, rated from movies"
        cur.execute(q)
        res = cur.fetchall()
        q = f"select showtimings from shows where movie_name = '{self.x}'"
        cur.execute(q)
        shows = cur.fetchall()
        self.dates = []
        present = datetime.now()

        for i in shows:
            if shows.index(i) < 8:
                x = datetime.strftime(i[0], '%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S')
                if datetime.strftime(i[0], '%d %B, %Y') not in self.dates and x > datetime.strftime(present.date(), '%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S'):
                    self.dates.append(datetime.strftime(
                        i[0], '%d %B, %Y %I:%M %p'))
        for i in res:
            if i[0] == self.x:
                self.movdesc, self.movposter, self.movie_price, self.movie_rating, self.cast, self.runtime, self.director, self.languages, self.genre, self.rated = i[
                    2], i[1], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7], i[8], i[9], i[10]

        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MovieInfoWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(770, -30, 870, 200))
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(r"CineDeck\assets\logo.svg"))
        self.RedHead = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.RedHead.setObjectName(u"RedHead")
        self.RedHead.setGeometry(QRect(0, -20, 1920, 150))
        self.RedHead.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 1)")
        #self.showtimes = QLabel((i for i in shows), self.centralwidget)
        #self.showtimes.setGeometry(QRect(1800, -30, 870, 200))
        self.bg = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.bg.setObjectName(u"bg")
        self.bg.setGeometry(QRect(500, 0, 1920, 1080))
        self.bookbutton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bookbutton.setObjectName(u"button")
        self.bookbutton.setGeometry(QRect(570, 800, 1300, 100))
        self.bookbutton.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{font-size: 40pt;background-color : rgba(18, 90, 128, 1)}")
        
        self.ShowTimings = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.ShowTimings.setObjectName(u"ShowTimings")
        self.ShowTimings.setGeometry(QRect(1500, 150, 800, 500))
        self.MovieInfo = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.MovieInfo.setObjectName(u"Cast")
        self.MovieInfo.setGeometry(QRect(575, 280, 800, 500))
        self.MovieInfo.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 15pt;}")
        self.MovieInfo.setWordWrap(True)
        self.MovieInfo.setFont(font)

        self.movpos = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.movpos.setObjectName(u"movpos")
        self.movpos.setGeometry(QRect(50, 200, 500, 700))
        self.movpos.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(self.movposter))
        self.movpos.setScaledContents(True)

        self.Title = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setObjectName(u"Title")
        self.Title.setGeometry(QRect(570, 35, 40000, 400))
        self.Title.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 50pt;}")
        self.Title.setFont(font)
        self.availabel = QLabel("Available Timings", self.centralwidget)
        self.availabel.setGeometry(QRect(1550, 300, 350, 50))
        self.availabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 20pt;}")
        group = QButtonGroup()
        for i in range(len(self.dates)):
            mov = QPushButton(self.dates[i], self.centralwidget)
            group.addButton(mov, i)
            mov.setObjectName(f"mov_0{i}")
            mov.setGeometry(QRect(1575, 350 + 60*i, 250, 40))

        self.bg.raise_()
        self.RedHead.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.ShowTimings.raise_()
        self.MovieInfo.raise_()
        self.bookbutton.raise_()
        self.Title.raise_()
        self.movpos.raise_()
        # self.showtimes.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(MovieInfoWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MovieInfoWindow)
        MovieInfoWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.bookbutton.clicked.connect(self.openmoviebookingscreen)


    def retranslateUi(self, MovieInfoWindow):
        MovieInfoWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate(
            "MovieInfoWindow", u"MovieInfoWindow", None))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.RedHead.setText("")
        self.bookbutton.setText("BOOK NOW")
        self.bg.setText(QCoreApplication.translate(
            "MovieInfoWindow", u"", None))
        self.MovieInfo.setText(QCoreApplication.translate(
            "MovieInfoWindow", f"{self.movdesc}\nGenre : {self.genre}\nDirector : {self.director}\nAge Rating : {self.rated}\nRuntime : {self.runtime}\nCast : {self.cast}\nRating : {self.movie_rating}", None))
        self.movpos.setText(QCoreApplication.translate(
            "MovieInfoWindow", u"", None))
        self.Title.setText(QCoreApplication.translate(
            "MovieInfoWindow", self.x, None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MovieInfoWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when `self.bookbutton` is clicked its supposed to open the following window, however it doesn't

This is the code for the window that displays the showtimings.(`ui_booking.py`)

```
class Ui_MovieBookingWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.seats = Ui_SeatsWindow()

    def setupUi(self, MovieBookingWindow):
        if not MovieBookingWindow.objectName():
            MovieBookingWindow.setObjectName(u"MovieBookingWindow")
        MovieBookingWindow.resize(1920, 1080)
        q = f"SELECT movie_name, movie_poster, movie_desc, movie_price, movie_rating, cast, runtime, director, languages, genre, rated from movies where movie_name = '{x}'"
        cur.execute(q)
        res = cur.fetchall()
        for i in res:
            self.movdesc, self.movposter, self.movie_price, self.movie_rating, self.cast, self.runtime, self.director, self.languages, self.genre, self.rated = i[
                2], i[1], i[3], i[4], i[5], i[6], i[7], i[8], i[9], i[10]
        q = f"select * from shows where movie_name = '{x}'"
        cur.execute(q)
        shows = cur.fetchall()
        font = QFont()
        font.setFamily(u"Yu Gothic UI Light")
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(MovieBookingWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.label = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(770, -30, 870, 200))
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(r"CineDeck\assets\logo.svg"))
        self.RedHead = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.RedHead.setObjectName(u"RedHead")
        self.RedHead.setGeometry(QRect(0, -20, 1920, 150))
        self.RedHead.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: rgba(128, 0, 0, 1)")
        self.label.raise_()
        self.movpos = QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.movpos.setObjectName(u"movpos")
        self.movpos.setGeometry(QRect(50, 150, 500, 700))
        self.movpos.setPixmap(
            QPixmap(self.movposter))
        self.movpos.setScaledContents(True)

        self.dates = QButtonGroup()

        for i in enumerate(shows):
            showss = QPushButton(
                f"{datetime.strftime(i[1][2], '%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S')}", self.centralwidget)
            showss.setObjectName(
                f"{datetime.strftime(i[1][2], '%d %B, %Y %H:%M:%S')}")
            showss.setCheckable(True)
            self.dates.addButton(showss)
            showss.raise_()
            if i[0] < 10:
                showss.setGeometry(QRect(600, 300 + 60*i[0], 250, 40))
            if 10 < i[0] < 20:
                showss.setGeometry(QRect(600, 300 + 60*(i[0]-10), 250, 40))
            showss.clicked.connect(self.write)

        self.bookbutton = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bookbutton.setObjectName(u"button")
        self.bookbutton.setGeometry(QRect(570, 800, 1300, 100))
        self.bookbutton.setStyleSheet(
            "QPushButton{font-size: 40pt;background-color : rgba(128, 200, 128, 1)}")
        self.bookbutton.clicked.connect(self.showseats)
        # self.bookbutton.clicked.connect(self.openmoviebookingscreen)

        self.Title = QLabel(f"{x}", self.centralwidget)
        self.Title.setObjectName(u"Title")
        self.Title.setGeometry(QRect(570, 100, 4000, 200))
        self.Title.setStyleSheet("QLabel{font-size: 50pt;}")
        self.Title.setFont(font)
        MovieBookingWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MovieBookingWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MovieBookingWindow)

    def write(self):
        name = self.sender().objectName()
        with open(r'CineDeck\window_code\show.txt', 'w') as f:
            print(name)
            f.write(self.sender().objectName())

    def showseats(self):
        self.seats.setupUi(self)

    def retranslateUi(self, MovieBookingWindow):
        MovieBookingWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate(
            "MovieBookingWindow", u"MovieBookingWindow", None))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.bookbutton.setText("BOOK NOW")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MovieBookingWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

if i run the code of ui_movieinfo.py without running the main file(i have to login, select movie etc.), `self.bookbutton` works perfectly fine.

could someone help identify the error in this.

Comment: Typo: change to `self.booking` (remove the `setupUi()`, which was already done in the `__init__`, and is obviously wrong using `self` there, since it refers to another instance). Also: 1. don't try to mimic the behavior of PyUic file, nor "merge" their code unless you really understand it; 2. you should not call `setupUi` (or do what that function normally does) more than once on the same instance (as you did in `Ui_MovieBookingWindow`); 3. use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: Sorry, I was editing and I left out part of the code: `self.booking.show()` in `openmoviebookingscreen()`.

Comment: when i do `self.booking.show()` the window stays open, and opens the next open. how do i make the window close, and then open the next one

Comment: also, ive been using the `setupUi(self)` to open other windows and it works fine, the places where it doesnt work is when i open the homescreen after login and in the situation mentioned above

Comment: You must use `setupUi(self)` only on the correct instances (and only with unmodified pyuic objects). If you want to close a window, just call its `close()` or `hide()` or `setVisible(False)` functions. Note that if you want to show it again, you'll need to call `show()` or `setVisible(True)` on **the same** instance, not create a new one. You'll probably need to use custom signals, or at least make the other window a modal dialog.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but could you also tell what i have to change so i can continue with the `setupUi(self)` since im dealing with variables i store in a json, and when i use `show()`, the second file sets up along with the first one, and the variable change that takes place in the first file is not reflected in the second file.

Comment: The "reason" you're giving is completely unrelated, because it means that the problem is the way you're dealing with data. `setupUi()` should be called just *once* in each instance, possibly in the `__init__` of its class. If something must change in the *same* instance, then apply it just to what is actually changed, don't reload the whole ui on the same instance. I'm under the impression that you're making some confusion on the usage of classes and instances, the relations between objects and their persistence. I'd suggest you to do some research on the matter to better clarify those aspects

Comment: when i click the button for a certain movie(lets say A) , a json file gets updated and the name of the movie A is stored there and the booking window shows up with the information of A. when i run the program the next time, if i select another movie B, the next window always has the data of movie A. i did a print statement in the code for the second window to display the name of the movie in terminal. whenver i run the program for the first window to open, the code in the second window runs and it gets printed

Comment: I cannot help you debug your program, as its code is too convoluted, uses discouraged practices (the wrong usage of `setupUi()`) and has various issues (like unreferenced variables). If you want to switch "pages" in a single window, use QStackedWidget, do **not** overwrite its contents with `setupUi()`. Sorry but you need to completely rethink the whole structure, and refactor most of your code in order to *properly* use objects and instances.

Comment: thats ok. howver could you explain as to why in some instances the `setupUi()` works completely fine and in others it doesnt. This entire software is for a project i have to submit in around 3 days and im not sure i can completely change the code infrastructure in that much time